# Обновлять экран каждый раз при его открытии

Tags: flutter

Как выполнять запрос к api, каждый раз, когда открывается экран?
Сейчас после первого открытия экран сохраняется, и обновить его получается только при нажатии кнопки, или свайп вверх. Как сделать это автоматически, что бы каждый раз при открытии экрана выполнялся запрос к апи, и экран обновлялся?